# Type conversion c++, quadmath

Tags: c++, floating-point, complex-numbers, multiprecision

The quadmath library does not have much documentation online and I would like to perform two simple actions using `__complex128` type.

- Is there a way to easily print the value inside a variable of this type?
- How can I convert back a variable from `__complex128` to `complex<double>`, or even the single `__float128` real and imaginary parts to double?

The second question is more important because if I can convert it I can simply use `cout`!

**EDIT: Everything comes to the following question. How do I convert `__float128` to `double`?**

Comment: These links might help: [\[1\]](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2016-07/msg00120.html) [\[2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41776202/3282436)

Comment: Thank you for the links but it gives me an error: undefined reference to quadmath_snprintf. However I need mostly the conversion

Comment: @NSZ: That's s linker error. A wild guess would be that you have to link with libquadmath (try `-lquadmath`).

Comment: @You: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for my newbeness, but where do I put this command ( I am on windows).

Comment: @NSZ: Wherever linker flags go, which depends on what compiler/build system you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a `__float128` to a `double` does not require anything special:

```
const __float128 x{};
const double y = x;
```

You might want a `static_cast` for clarity (and less warnings).

Constructing a `std::complex<T>` from `__complex128` is [also not difficult](https://godbolt.org/g/o8FBN1):

```
auto bar(__complex128 y)
{
    return std::complex<double>{
        static_cast<double>(__real__ y),
        static_cast<double>(__imag__ y)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
std::complex<double> x;
__complex128 y;
x.real(__real__ y)
x.imag(__imag__ y)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The error message is: "error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)"

Comment: [`real`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real) and [`imag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag) are member _functions_ of `std::complex`.

Comment: Probably need `x.real(__real__ y)` etc.

Comment: Updated the answer per @n.m.'s comment. Thank you guys.